# Processing of an html-form that consists of buttons

Tags: php, html

I have an html-form which includes some information to be sent to the php-script. The type of an input of this information is "button". It is important that all the values are saved.

```
<form name="CoordinatesReceiving" method="get" action="MainScript.php">
   <p> Insert the coordinates of the point: </p>
   <label> Insert X <input type="button" name="xCoordinate" id="xCoordinate" value="1"> </label> <br>
   <label> Insert R <input type="button" name="radius" id="radius" value="5"> </label> <br>
   <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send.">
</form>
```

The form has to "remember" that I pressed these buttons and send them to the server.
How can I implement this?

Comment: You have to do that in JavaScript. Buttons don't send a value to the server by themselves, except the submit button.

Comment: Why are you using buttons instead of checkboxes?

Comment: It's a task. I have to get the values of the form using buttons and send them to a php-script where they will be processed.

Comment: You need JavaScript. When you click on a button it can save the value in a hidden input, and that will be sent to PHP.

Comment: Buttons don't do anything automatically.

Comment: Could you give an example of such a script on JavaScript, please?

Comment: `document.getElementById("radius").onclick = function() { document.getElementById("hidden-radius").value = this.value; }`

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! What do you mean by "hidden-radius"?

Comment: You need to add hidden inputs to the form that correspond to each button. So `<input type="hidden" name="radius" id="hidden-radius">` will send the data from the `radius` button.

Comment: I'm trying not to write the whole thing for you, just point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Thank you. You've actually given the answer to my main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for the x-button:

```
<label for="xCoordinate">Insert X</label>
<input type="button" name="xCoordinate" id="xCoordinate" onclick="this.value=1">
```

Comment: You can get the value from your script.

Comment: Thank you. It was a good idea to create separate buttons instead of adding it one-by-one inside one label.